# how to allow users to rate a product only once,

Tags: django

a Reviews model linked to Users and Product, nothing special,

users can vote as much as they want which is working,

but i'm stuck restricting the rating to just once

the view so far:

```
class ReviewCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Review
    form_class = ReviewForm
    template_name = "form.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('product_list')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

model

```
class Review(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True,related_name='reviews')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True,related_name='reviewers')
    rating = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

the other models wouldn't help that muc ,**Product** just describe a product ,and default (regular) **User** model

the form is *ModelForm* based on the *Review Model* itself

any suggestion is welcome, even if i have to redo the model, thank you very much

Comment: can you update the post with the product model ?

Answer (score 1):

1. set db constraint like so:

```
class Meta: 
    constraints = [
        UniqueConstraint([fields=['user', 'product'], name='product_user_unique'),
    ]
```

2. the condition for your views would be like this:

```
def get(self, request, product):
    if (Review.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        .filter(product_id=product).exists():
        # probably, you'd want to pass some 
        # conditional data to the template's context here
        do_something()
```

That could be it. You restrict non-unique reviews by UI, but if it's somehow bypassed, user will get a server error. Of course, you could also apply validation in your `CreateView` (or analogous).

Comment: thank you very much i'll try this aproach, seems good

Answer (score 0):

From architectural standpoint, you can always create a `review_user` table which will have the `Product ID`, and the `ID of the users` who voted on that product.. and upon second vote, you check if there's already a vote in the table.

Once you have this understanding, I am sure that you will find a way to incorporate the logic within your code.